# Symfony2 - 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active file] on line 0

Tags: symfony, serialization

I'm sending some kind of events to Mixpanel. So I've created a service where the events are configured and transformed into Javascript Mixpanel API methods by `json_encode` function.

This Json object containing events is called from a Twig template:

```
{{ mixpanel.consumeJavascriptActions | raw }}
```

and it works right almost always, but when I call the service from inside an Event Listener:

```
function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->newProposals = array();
    $ormUtils = new DoctrineOrmUtils($this->doctrine->getManager());
    foreach ($args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof Proposal) {
            $this->newProposals[] = $entity;
        }

    }
}

function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    foreach ($this->newProposals as $proposal) {

        //Here I call the service
        $this->get('pro_mixpanel')->trackCommunityChanges($proposal->getCommunity(), $this->getUser());

     }

}
```

and I'm getting the next error when the Event `new Proposal` is fired:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active file] on line 0
>
> Exception: Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed in [no active file] on line 0

And a long list of errors like these:

> Exception: Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed
>
> Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

and a few more `Serialization of ... not allowed`.

I don't know how to solve it, since I'm not sending any XML data, and it works right when I call this service from inside a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was just an error on my data to encode to a Json object. There was a value from the array to encode that was also an array. Fixing it all works right.